# Angular4 - Central error Logging and handling for all http requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-http, angular2-observables

I have developed the following wrapper class for all my http calls. I have just included the get function in the example

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * Wrapper around the Http provider to allow customizing HTTP requests
 */
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {
    private httpParams: HttpParams;
    private httpHeaders: HttpHeaders;

    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private sharedService: SharedService) {
        this.httpParams = new HttpParams();
        this.httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });

    }

    public get<T>(url: string, httpParams: Array<Map<string, string>>) {
        return this.httpClient
            .get<T>(url, { params: this.appendHttpParams(httpParams), headers: this.httpHeaders })
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

    }

    private appendHttpParams(paramArray: Array<Map<string, string>>): HttpParams {
        paramArray.forEach((value: Map<string, string>, index: number, array: Array<Map<string, string>>) => {
            this.httpParams.append(value.keys[index], value.values[index]);
        });
        return this.httpParams;

    }
}
```

This works fine. But when I try to call the get from a custom service as follows

```
this.httpClientService.get<StoredAppData[]>(this.configService.urls.fetchSettings, params)
    .map((response) => {
        this.storedAppData = response.json();
        console.log(this.storedAppData);
        return this.storedAppData;
    });
```

It throws a TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subscription'error. I understand that I have already subscribed to the Observable and would work well if I get rid of the .subscribe() and just return the function. However, then I cannot implement central error handling on a single layer. What could be a good way to do it?

Comment: public get<T>(url: string, httpParams: Array<Map<string, string>>) {
        var response = this.httpClient
            .get<T>(url, { params: this.appendHttpParams(httpParams), headers: this.httpHeaders });
        response.subscribe(data => {
        },
            err => {
            });
        return response;
    }

Comment: Got to be a more elegant method than the one above.

Comment: simply add this line `import 'rxjs/add/observable/map';` to remove error about `map`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. If I return the get call without the subscribe() it doesn't throw the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type error addresses actual problem in code. A subscription shouldn't be returned from a method that is supposed to return an observable:

```
const response$ = this.httpClient.get<T>(...)
response$.subscribe(data => ..., err => ...);
return response$;
```

Unless returning a hot observable is a desirable effect, `subscribe` shouldn't be performed in service itself at all. Instead, [`do` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-do)  should be used for side effects:

> This operator is useful for debugging your Observables for the correct values or performing other side effects.
>
> Note: this is different to a subscribe on the Observable. If the Observable returned by do is not subscribed, the side effects specified by the Observer will never happen. do therefore simply spies on existing execution, it does not trigger an execution to happen like subscribe does.

```
return this.httpClient.get<T>(...)
.do(data => ..., err => ...);
```

Comment: Are there any recommended patterns available for the use of reactive programming in Angular 4?

Comment: @lohiarahul Nothing specific, general knowledge of RxJS 5 is enough. If you're new to RxJS you can check http://www.learnrxjs.io/ first, because RxJS 5 documentation is awful, and RxJS 4 documentation is ok but its API differs too much.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it by replacing .subscribe() with .do() operator.